# Angular 2 передача данными между компонентами через router-outlet

Tags: angular2, typescript

Задача такая: есть главный компонент, у него через router-outlet отрисован дочерний. Мне нужно передать в дочерний компонент данные (если быть точным, массив), при этом, чтобы компонент мог изменять его и эти изменения синхронно приходили к главному компоненту. Не могу точно понять, как это нужно делать: через queryParams, или же через службы/провайдеры, или же через inputs/outputs (как тогда через router-outlet тег передавать данные в инпуты?) Если нужен код, могу прикрепить, но, как мне кажется, суть вопроса понятна и без кода.

Answer (score 1):

**Обновление 1**

С моей точки зрения это должно выглядеть примерно так:

chat.service.ts

`public fetchMessages(user1Id, user2Id)` - возвращает сообщения между user1Id и user2Id

и такой роут: chat/:userId , userId - urlParams, например, при переходе в chat/3 будут загружаться сообщения с пользователем с id 3, это user2id. user1Id - Это авторизованный пользователь.

chat.component.ts

```
activeUserId: number;
userId: number;
messages: any;
userService.activeUserChanges.subscribe(activeUserId => this.activeUserId = activeUserId);
urlParams.subscribe(userId => { 
    this.messages = chatService.fetchMessages(this.activeUserId, userId);
    this.userId = userId;
```

}

**Оригинал**

Т.к. нужно отлавливать изменения в родительском компоненте из router-outlet, то через сервис

parent.component.ts

```
sharedDataService.data.subcribe(data => this.arr = data);
```

child.component.ts

```
sharedDataService.data.emit(data);
```

shared-data.service.ts

```
private arr: any[];
public data: EventEmitter<any[]>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Теперь уточню:
мой проект - чат. Родительский комп-т - список друзей, дочерний - сообщения с ними соответственно. 
Пока что у меня готова такая маршрутизация: я добавляю друга, начинаю с ним диалог - пишу сообщения. Переключаюсь на другого друга, но сообщения с предыдущим у меня отображаются и в диалоге  с текущим. Соотв-но, мне нужно сделать, чтобы каждый друг "запоминал" сообщения с ним и отображал нужное при выборе его. Конкретно ваша рекомендация подойдет именно для моего проекта? Просто уже 3 дня бьюсь с этим, столько всего лишнего перечитал, но сервисы пока не трогал.